# Where does blackbox exporter store probe data?

Tags: docker, prometheus, exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I want to store blackbox-exporter probe data through volume mount so that when blackbox container is restarted for any reason, previous probe data is available.
Any way I can achieve this? I want to know where is the probe data stored inside the container so that I can persist it via volume mount.

Side question: Is it a good idea to store blackbox exporter probe data or persisting prometheus data is good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the UI is only stored in memory, as it's only intended for occasional debugging.

Generally you should rely on Prometheus to store the metrics.